# Не работает условие jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

По первому значению `val` всё срабатывает как надо, а `Quantity-8` уже нет.
В чем ошибка может быть?

И еще, как сделать такое же условие, но уже со стороны выбора месяца?
Например выбираем `option` c `value === '3months'` и становятся неактивными `option` c `value` равным `Quantity-4` и `Quantity-8`

```js
$('#quantity').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === 'Quantity-4' && 'Quantity-8') {
    $('#3mon').attr('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#3mon').attr('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap-calc">
  <label for="quantity">Quantity of lessons</label>
  <select id="quantity" name="quantity">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="Quantity-4">4 lessons</option>
    <option value="Quantity-8">8 lessons</option>
    <option value="Quantity-12">12 lessons</option>
    <option value="Quantity-36">36 lessons</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="wrap-calc">
  <label for="validity">Plan validity</label>
  <select id="validity" name="validity">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option id="1mon" value="1month">One month</option>
    <option id="3mon" value="3months">Three months</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы понимаете, что конструкция `&& 'Quantity-8'` - это приведение строки к boolean (в данном случае к `true`, так как строка не пустая), а итоговое `&& true` бесполезно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вариант с выбором срока обучения, а уже после количеством лекций, от себя я хотел бы сказать что если есть возможность (как в вашем случае) лучше использовать значения в селекте лишь числовые, т.е. вместе: 1month и 3months просто 1 и 3, также и с селектом где id="quantity":

```js
$(document).on('change', '#validity', function() {
  $('#quantity').prop('disabled', false); // делаем активным выбор уроков
  $('#quantity option').removeAttr('disabled'); // очищаем все элементы
  $('#quantity').val('0'); // сбрасываем значение селекта
  
  if ($(this).val() == '1') { // и блокируем элементы
    $('#quantity option[value="12"], #quantity option[value="36"]').attr('disabled', '');
  } else {
    $('#quantity option[value="4"], #quantity option[value="8"]').attr('disabled', '');
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap-calc">
  <label for="validity">Plan validity</label>
  <select id="validity" name="validity">
    <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">How much will we learn?</option>
    <option value="1">One month</option>
    <option value="3">Three months</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="wrap-calc">
  <label for="quantity">Quantity of lessons</label>
  <select id="quantity" name="quantity" disabled="">
    <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">Select lesson</option>
    <option value="4">4 lessons</option>
    <option value="8">8 lessons</option>
    <option value="12">12 lessons</option>
    <option value="36">36 lessons</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#quantity').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === 'Quantity-4' || $(this).val() === 'Quantity-8') {
    $('#3mon').attr('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#3mon').attr('disabled', false);
  }
});

$('#validity').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === '3months') {
    $('option[value="Quantity-4"], option[value="Quantity-8"]').attr('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#quantity option[value="Quantity-4"], option[value="Quantity-8"]').attr('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap-calc">
  <label for="quantity">Quantity of lessons</label>
  <select id="quantity" name="quantity">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="Quantity-4">4 lessons</option>
    <option value="Quantity-8">8 lessons</option>
    <option value="Quantity-12">12 lessons</option>
    <option value="Quantity-36">36 lessons</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="wrap-calc">
  <label for="validity">Plan validity</label>
  <select id="validity" name="validity">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option id="1mon" value="1month">One month</option>
    <option id="3mon" value="3months">Three months</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: может этот код все же как-то поизящнее можно написать?

Answer (score 0):

У вас была ошибка в условии, так будет правильней:

```js
$('#quantity').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('#validity option').removeAttr('disabled');
  if (val === 'Quantity-4' || val === 'Quantity-8') {
    $('#3mon').attr('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#1mon').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```css
По первому значению val всё срабатывает как надо,
а Quantity-8 уже нет. В чем ошибка может быть? И еще - как сделать такое же условие,
но уже со стороны выбора месяца? Например выбираем option c value==='3months' и становятся неактивными option c value Quantity-4 иQuantity-8
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap-calc">
  <label for="quantity">Quantity of lessons</label>
  <select id="quantity" name="quantity">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="Quantity-4">4 lessons</option>
    <option value="Quantity-8">8 lessons</option>
    <option value="Quantity-12">12 lessons</option>
    <option value="Quantity-36">36 lessons</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="wrap-calc">
  <label for="validity">Plan validity</label>
  <select id="validity" name="validity">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option id="1mon" value="1month">One month</option>
    <option id="3mon" value="3months">Three months</option>
  </select>
</div>
```